# How to style slot elements in Astro with Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css, astrojs

How can i style the injected elements in an Astro layout using plain css with tailwind.

Minimum Reproducible example:

**/src/layouts/PostLayout.astro**

```
<div class="prose text-white">
<slot/>
</div>
```

**/pages/somepage.mdx**

```
---
layout: ../layouts/PostLayout.astro
---
# Header 1
 Some text
```

How can i target the markdown elements that are injected into the slot?

I can easily target any of the defined elements that are in the layout using a style block like this:

```
<style>
    div {
       border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

However any styles applied to elements in the slot are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

This solution isn't with Tailwind but maybe someone might find it useful

```
<style is:inline>
    h1 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 2rem;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Astro docs:

Scoped Styles

https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#scoped-styles

> Astro  CSS rules are automatically scoped by default. Scoped styles are compiled behind-the-scenes to only apply to HTML written inside of that same component. **The CSS that you write inside of an Astro component is automatically encapsulated inside of that component.**

Global Styles

https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#global-styles

> Astro  CSS rules are automatically scoped by default. Scoped styles are compiled behind-the-scenes to only apply to HTML written inside of that same component. The CSS that you write inside of an Astro component is automatically encapsulated inside of that component.[...]
> Global Styles
> While we recommend scoped styles for most components, you may eventually find a valid reason to write global, unscoped CSS. **You can opt-out of automatic CSS scoping with the <style is:global> attribute.**

Add style tag in your file, with a `is:global` directive:

```
<div class="prose text-white">
<slot/>
</div>

<style is:global>
    div {
       border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

If you prefer using **tailwind** classes:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply

```
<style is:global>
  div {
    @apply border-2 border-black;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: In WebComponents we can use ::slotted(*) to style slotted elements. There should be a similar solution in Astro.

Answer (score 0):

`<style>` elements are [scoped by default](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#scoped-styles), to opt out of scoping in the `<style>` tag you can use [Global Styling](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#global-styles) or the [`is:global` directive](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#isglobal). (Reccomended)

Since markdown HTML is generated programmatically the only way to style your markdown using tailwind classes would be

1. (Reccomended) Tailwind's [typography plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin)
2. Remove the default tailwind base using [this config option](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/tailwind/#configapplybasestyles) and add your own that includes the [`@layer` and `@apply`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer) directives
3. A markdown plugin like [rehype-add-classes](https://github.com/martypdx/rehype-add-classes) which allows you to add classes by selector to elements inside your markdown HTML

It is generally recommended to use [Global Styling](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#global-styles) or the [typography plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin) to style markdown in Astro