# Astro markdown not rendered in live preview and finished build

Tags: markdown, astrojs

I am exploring [Astro](https://astro.build/) a bit and so far so good, except one important issue I am not able to pinpoint as of yet.

Basically, when I write a post in markdown, it renders ok in any markdown previewer, so the syntax seems ok, but for some reason it does not render in the final product nor in the preview when `npm run dev`

What am I doing wrong?

Here is an image:

[neovim and local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wEQS.png)

I tried different formatting, and at some point I thought neovim was causing the issue somehow but that does not seem to be the case.

I haven't found any similar case yet googling around.

Comment: It looks like your markdown does not have any CSS styling, this question might have the answer your looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/75090873/6909829

Comment: Thank you so much, it does seem related to tailwind indeed as removing it from the config pretty much fixes all of the issues and oddities I was seeing